# How to create private methods that can be redefined in subclasses in Dart?

Tags: inheritance, dart, private-methods

Whenever I define a private method like this:

```dart
class ParentClass {

  sayHi() { _initiateGreeting(); }
  _initiateGreeting() { print("I'm a parent class"); }

}
```

It is not possible to redefine it in a subclass:

```dart
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
  _initiateGreeting() { print("I'm a child class"); } // redefining the method
}
```

Now if I create an instance of a `ChildClass` and call `sayHi()` method, then it is the private method from a `ParentClass` which actually gets called:

```dart
var child = new ChildClass();
child.sayHi(); // outputs "I'm a parent class"
```

If, however, `_initiateGreeting()` is made public everywhere (that is, stripped off the `_`) then calling `child.sayHi()` results in the output `I'm a child class`.

Why? How do I redefine a private method so that it gets called in a subclass?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Private member* can be seen as *library member*. Inside a library there are no difference between members with or without a prepending underscore.

So if you're in the same library you should be able to redefined the method in subclass.

Comment: This is interesting. But what if `ParentClass` belongs to a library - that is there's a `part of` statement at the top of the file which holds the `ParentClass`, while `ChildClass` isn't a part of that library (which is, ironically, my case)?

Comment: Is it expected that `ChildClass` does not extend `ParentClass` in your code snippet ? `part of` should not have an impact on privacy.

Comment: I did some digging and it looks like `part of` statement actually affects whether I can redefine a private method or not: https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!msg/misc/XZ0pqeqCeVs/j3QdGO_ZZmUJ

Comment: Florian gives the same explanation as my answer. Prepending underscore means _library private_. `part of` is only a way to cut one library into multiple parts but it remains the same library.

Answer (score 0):

What you are essentially asking for are protected methods. Alas, Dart doesn't have any.

But there is a very simple workaround, that might not be elegant, but nonetheless effective.

Just define a class `ProtectedMethod` within the same library as your `MyClass`. `ProtectedMember` has one private member--the "protected" method. `MyClass` then has a field `protectedMethod` of type `ProtectedMethod`. A consumer of your `MyClass` will of course see `protectedMethod`, but can't access the actual method. A user who subclasses your `MyMethod` just has to create a new `ProtectedMethod` and override the method in the constructor.

This approach might even have advantages, as this enables you to do sanity checks or force to call `super` without relying on flimsy annotations.